# New Year's fun: virtual silly hats - should this site join in?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Across the Stack Exchange, at the end of December and start of January for the last two years, they've had virtual hats as rewards for various site participation activities.

As a site, we can choose to opt in to this [Hat Dash](http://winterba.sh/), if we want. There will be a range of overlays [image]
that you can add to your icon
[image]

If you yourself want to abstain, then that's ok: there will be a button that will allow you to opt out personally from the whole thing.

Should this site as a whole take part?

**Update**: A (small) majority is in favor so we've opted our site in. The winter bash will start at december 16th.

Comment: EnergyNumbers, thanks for starting this poll. Are you also going to notify the SE staff that we will be participating if the "yes" wins it from the "no"?.

Comment: For people who want to know more, [here's the 2012 blog announcing the start of the winterbash](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/12/welcome-to-winter-bash-2012/). And here's [another blog about the results](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/01/boxing-day/).  There's also a picture of me with an antlers hat half-way down the second blog :-)

Comment: @THelper, yes, all being well, I'll fill the form in, and leave a note here. If you don't see a note left here by this time next week, please do fill in the form (via the link in today's moderator email).

Comment: I've opted us in

Comment: This question is now surplus to requirements. We have opted in to hats

Answer (score 1):

I'm in favor of hats!

[image: THelper with hat]